# how to print the innertext of an element based on attribute search of a particular node using LINQ?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

**I have an XML like this-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Tool_Parent>
    <tool name="ABCD" id="226">
        <category>Centralized</category>
        <extension_id>0</extension_id>
        <uses_ids>16824943 16824944</uses_ids>
    </tool>
    <tool name="EFGH" id="228">
        <category>Automated</category>
        <extension_id>0</extension_id>
        <uses_ids>92440 16824</uses_ids>
    </tool>
</Tool_Parent>
```

Based on the id of tool i want to print the uses_ids value,i.e if i search for 228 i should get 92440 16824.
I had tried like-

```
var toolData = (from toolElement in doc.Descendants("tool")
               select new Tool_poco
               {
                a_Name = tool.Attribute("name").Value,
                a_Id = tool.Attribute("id").Value,
                e_ExtensionId = tool.Element("extension_id").Value,
                e_UsesIds =tool.Element("uses_parm_ids").Value
               });
```

where Tool_poco is a poco class for tool node containing declaration for member variable.
Now I want to get information related to a particular tool id in toolData variable.How to do it?

Note: I have variable like-

```
searched_Tool_id = Tool_Id_txtBx.Text.ToString();
```

Please let me know a way through which i can modify my above query for toolData.**

Comment: Do you want the value of `uses_ids` when you pass your `id` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could start by doing something like this once you have an XDocument object loaded and ready:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(
            @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                <Tool_Parent>
                  <tool name=""ABCD"" id=""226"">
                    <category>Centralized</category>
                    <extension_id>0</extension_id>
                    <uses_ids>16824943 16824944</uses_ids>
                  </tool>
                  <tool name=""EFGH"" id=""228"">
                    <category>Automated</category>
                    <extension_id>0</extension_id>
                    <uses_ids>92440 16824</uses_ids>
                  </tool>
                </Tool_Parent>");


        var root = xdoc.Root; // Got to have that root

        if (root != null)
        {
            var id228query = (from toolElement in root.Elements("tool")
                where toolElement.HasAttributes
                where toolElement.Attribute("id").Value.Equals("228")
                let xElement = toolElement.Element("uses_ids")
                where xElement != null
                select xElement.Value).FirstOrDefault();

            Console.WriteLine(id228query);

            Console.Read();
        }


Output: 92440 16824


**Note: In reference to your example, one possible reason it was not working
for you could be that your xml references an element with name "uses_ids",
however, your query references an element with a similar, but not exact, 
spelling with name "uses_parm_ids".**
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your query as

```
 Tool_poco toolData = (from el in xelement.Elements("Employee")
                        where (string)el.Attribute("id") == "226"
                        select new Tool_poco
                        {
                            a_Name = el.Attribute("name").Value,
                            a_Id = el.Attribute("id").Value,
                            e_ExtensionId = el.Element("Name").Value,
                            e_UsesIds = el.Element("uses_ids").Value
                        }).FirstOrDefault();
```